# AWS EKS - Kubernetes client throwing a 401 Unauthorized, what permissions are needed to make requests to the Core API?

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-eks

I can generate the kubeconfig with the configured credentials:

```bash
aws eks update-kubeconfig --name <cluster-name> --region <region> --kubeconfig /tmp/kubeconfig
```

But when trying to list the pods, I'm getting the following error:

```
HTTP response headers: HTTPHeaderDict({'Audit-Id': 'xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx', 'Cache-Control': 'no-cache, private', 'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Date': 'Thu, 29 Sep 2022 17:41:09 GMT', 'Content-Length': '129'})
HTTP response body: {"kind":"Status","apiVersion":"v1","metadata":{},"status":"Failure","message":"Unauthorized","reason":"Unauthorized","code":401}
```

I'm using the k8s Python client:

```py
from kubernetes import client as k8s_client                                                                               
from kubernetes import config as k8s_config              
                                                                                                                                  
k8s_api_client = k8s_client.ApiClient(k8s_config.load_kube_config('/tmp/kubeconfig'))                                      
core_v1_api = k8s_client.CoreV1Api(k8s_api_client)
pods_raw = core_v1_api.list_pod_for_all_namespaces(watch=False).to_dict()
```

I have no direct access to the cluster (I'm just a "client"), so I cannot provide the current policies at the moment.

Full trace:

```
19:41:09    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/kubernetes/client/api/core_v1_api.py", line 17309, in list_pod_for_all_namespaces
19:41:09      return self.list_pod_for_all_namespaces_with_http_info(**kwargs)  # noqa: E501
19:41:09    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/kubernetes/client/api/core_v1_api.py", line 17430, in list_pod_for_all_namespaces_with_http_info
19:41:09      collection_formats=collection_formats)
19:41:09    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/kubernetes/client/api_client.py", line 353, in call_api
19:41:09      _preload_content, _request_timeout, _host)
19:41:09    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/kubernetes/client/api_client.py", line 184, in __call_api
19:41:09      _request_timeout=_request_timeout)
19:41:09    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/kubernetes/client/api_client.py", line 377, in request
19:41:09      headers=headers)
19:41:09    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/kubernetes/client/rest.py", line 244, in GET
19:41:09      query_params=query_params)
19:41:09    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/kubernetes/client/rest.py", line 234, in request
19:41:09      raise ApiException(http_resp=r)
19:41:09  kubernetes.client.exceptions.ApiException: (401)
19:41:09  Reason: Unauthorized
```

Comment: The configuration file that `aws eks update-kubeconfig` generates depends on having AWS credentials available, whether via the `~/.aws/config` file or the `AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID` and related environment variables or elsewhere.  Are these set up correctly?  Can you run `kubectl version` outside your script?